Simple HTML formatting with images. Super new at coding/html
I'm just wondering how I can make it so that I have a clear division between list items without copy and pasting <br/> tags. I thought that if the image is contained within the <p> tag and that tag is closed prior to the next entry, that that would effectively "press enter" (if you will), so that the next header or text bit doesn't wrap around the image of the previous list item. I feel like I'm missing something simple here.


<li><h5>Artificial intelligence (AI)</h5>
<p><img src="AI.jpg" width="150" height="150" align="left" hspace="10"/> AI systems were limited in their capabilities,
but recent advancements have propelled AI into the mainstream. Today, various AI models power virtual assistants, 
business process management, and advanced data analytics. In just a short period, AI is predicted to become an 
integral part of our lives.</p> </li>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>



I tried to contain the image tag within the paragraph tag of the list item, thinking that this would naturally create a space between the next entry of the list.

Why not CSS? li { margin-bottom: 2em; } should be plenty...

It's not clear to me what your design goal is. Could you make a simple mockup in paint or something? Also, flexbox froggy or css grid garden might be good for learning the basics of flex & grid layouts.

If you want to separate list items without using multiple <br> tags, you can simply use CSS to style your list items and create separation between them. Here is the code :
CSS
<style>
.list-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.list-item img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>

HTML
<ul>
  <li class="list-item">
    <h5>Artificial intelligence (AI)</h5>
    <p><img src="AI.jpg" width="150" height="150" /> AI systems were limited in their capabilities, but recent advancements have propelled AI into the mainstream. Today, various AI models power virtual assistants, business process management, and advanced data analytics. In just a short period, AI is predicted to become an integral part of our lives.</p>
  </li>
  
  <li class="list-item">
    <h5>Another item</h5>
    <p><img src="another_image.jpg" width="150" height="150" /> Description of the second item goes here.</p>
  </li>
  
  <!-- Add more list items as needed -->
</ul>


Please read the AI Policy which forbids the use of AI-generated content on this site.
